# Show React Native app in "Open in" dialogue of another app

Tags: reactjs, share, native

I'm new at creating React Native apps and I would like to know if there is a doc or a package that allow us to open my app from an external one by clicking on the "share" button, that open the "open in... / share" dialogue modal

Thanks by advance

EDIT :

I have read the instructions given in the following link : [React Native Share Extension](https://github.com/alinz/react-native-share-extension)
but the thing is that it asks to edit some Java files for Android, and other ones for iOS. Since I'm working with javascript files, where am I supposed to find the files the documentation tells me to edit ?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built-it to do this, but there's also some useful packages for doing that, the catch is that you will need to write some native code to make it work

first there is [React-native-share-extension](https://github.com/alinz/react-native-share-extension) forn handle share intents, and for more advanced stuff there is [react-native-deep-link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-deep-link) for handling for example an url of a video, or a download url, or a mail intent .

Both packages requires to edit native ;-;

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at this